# Keep only lines in txt files that contain a certain word/character (Powershell) (Windows batch file)

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch

I want to keep only the lines that contain the word `example` and remove all other lines.

I thought this would work but it does the opposite to what I am trying to do:

```
PowerShell -Command "gci *.txt | foreach { (cat $_.FullName | ? { $_ -notlike '*example*' }) | set-content $_.FullName}"
```

I want to end up with a command that turns this:

```
This line contains example.
This line does not.
```

Into this:

```
This line contains example.
```

This seems like it should be simple but I can't find any answer to it. Solutions I have found have either not worked, or they do the opposite, or they include a bunch of other stuff I don't need to do.

Cheers.

Comment: What happens if you use `gci *.txt | foreach { (cat $_.FullName | ? { $_ -like '*example*' }) | set-content $_.FullName}`?

Comment: It works, you have solved it! Thanks. I would mark this as the right answer but it's in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current command uses `-notlike`; meaning you don't want lines that have the word `example` which is the opposite of what you really want. Use instead `-like`. Your command will be:

```
PowerShell -Command "gci *.txt | foreach { (cat $_.FullName | ? { $_ -like '*example*' }) | set-content $_.FullName}"
```

Comment: Cheers. I ran it on about 2,000 text files. If there was no line in the txt file with the string, it leaves all lines alone - when it should be leaving behind a 0 KB file? I tested this by deliberately adding the string to the first line in such files and then it does remove every other line, leaving only the first. That's a bit strange but I can still work around it and weed out the files with the string on any line (using Agent Ransack to search) and end up with only lines containing the string.